# Xamarin Forms NFC UWP SubscribeForMessage Problem

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin Forms app that reads/writes NFC tags with an NDEF text record (Guid). The app should read the already NDEF formatted tag and if it has a valid Guid just display a message. If the tag does not have a valid Guid it should write one to the tag. The app works fine in Android but in UWP SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", NDEFHandler)... is not triggered when an empty formatted tag is placed on the NFC sensor. If I subscribe also to SubscribeForMessage("WriteableTag", WriteableTagHandler)... the event is triggered on UWP. Unfortunately the "WriteableTag" event is always triggered before the "NDEF" event when I subscribe to both so I cant check if the tag has a Guid in the "WriteableTag" handler. If the events worked the other way around everything would be fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Paul.

I have tried SubscribeForMessage("NDEF:Empty", EmptyHandler)... but this also does not work.

SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", NDEFHandler) - Only triggered on already written tags.

SubscribeForMessage("WriteableTag", WriteableTagHandler) - Triggered on all formatted tags including empty tags.

SubscribeForMessage("NDEF:Empty", EmptyHandler) - Get an exception here!

I would like to first check if the tag has a valid Guid then if not write one to the tag.